# Delete associated thumbnails when calling wp_delete_attachment

Tags: attachments, thumbnails, customization

I have a somewhat straightforward script that allows users to upload their own avatar from the front-end. Another script allows them to delete their avatar, before uploading another. The image/attachment ID for each avatar is stored as user meta.

When the user chooses to delete their avatar, I call wp_delete_attachment() like so

```
    //DELETE AVATAR
    if( $_POST['explorer_delete_avatar'] == 'on' ) {
        $attachmentID = get_field('explorer_profile_custom_avatar', 'user_'.$userID);
        if( wp_delete_attachment($attachmentID, true) !== false ) {
            $user_meta['explorer_profile_custom_avatar'] = '';
        }
        else {
            $errors[] = 'Could not delete your profile portrait.';
        }
    }
```

This properly deletes the original file that was uploaded, but not any of the thumbnails that were generated.

I'm seeking the most efficient way to also delete the thumbnails. A few searches didn't reveal anything in the Codex or readily apparent on Google. Something tells me this should be fairly straight-forward. Any suggestions for a fellow hacker?

**Here's a bit more on my script's workflow**

```
<?php
//FORM NOT SUBMITTED, ALLOW UPLOAD
if( !$_POST ) {
    echo '<form action="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="explorerAvatarUpload">';
    echo '<label for="explorer_avatar_src">Please choose a file for your portrait.</label>';
    echo '<input type="file" name="explorer_avatar_src" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="explorer_portrait_upload_submit" value="Upload Portrait" />';
    echo '</form>';
}

if( $_POST['explorer_portrait_upload_submit'] ) {
//UPLOAD SUBMITTED, ADD AS ATTACHMENT
//HANDLE THE UPLOAD
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    $imgID = media_handle_upload('explorer_avatar_src', 0); //Passed to the crop form as a hidden field

    //SHOW THE CROPPER
    // Basic implementation of jCrop, ManifestCrop class handles showing the appropriate JS and hidden form fields
    echo '<h4>Crop your profile portrait</h4>';
    echo 'Drag and drop over the large image to crop.';
    $crop = new ManifestCrop($imgID, 110, 110);
    $crop->showCropper();
}

//The crop has been designated and dimensions are available
if( $_POST['crop_submit'] ) {
    $src_path = get_attached_file($_POST['imgID']);

    //Instantiate WP_Image_Editor class for cropping
    $img = wp_get_image_editor($src_path);
    $img->crop($_POST['crop_x'], $_POST['crop_y'], $_POST['crop_w'], $_POST['crop_h'], 110, 110);
    $saved = $img->save($src_path); //We've saved a new image, but it's unattached

    //Delete the original upload (uncropped source image)
    wp_delete_attachment($_POST['imgID'], true);

    //Attach the new image (cropped down to 110x110)
    $args = array(
    'guid' => $saved['path'],
    'post_mime_type' => $saved['mime-type'],
    'post_title' => basename($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $imgID = wp_insert_attachment($args, $saved['path'], 0);

    //Regenerate the attachment's metadata (for the cropped image)
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    $attachment_metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($imgID, $saved['path']);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($imgID, $attachment_metadata);

    //UPDATE THE USER META
    $prev_avatar = get_user_meta($userID, 'explorer_profile_custom_avatar', true);
    $prev_avatar = $prev_avatar ? $prev_avatar : '';
    update_field('explorer_profile_custom_avatar', $_POST['imgID'], 'user_'.$userID);
}
?>
```

Comment: `wp_delete_attachment()` also deletes other additional sizes too. Information about those sizes are saved as post meta, so might be there's issue how you upload and save avatars as attachments.

Comment: Hmm... I'm digging into this a bit, but still not having much luck. wp_delete_attachment() deletes some, but not all of the images.

Comment: If you can share the code you're using to upload avatars, it would help us to define problem much easier.

Comment: Thanks @Mamaduka - Just wanted to get my code cleaned up a bit for readability's sake.

Comment: Wait a second. You fetch a file, crop it, save it with the same name, then try to delete it? Doesn't make sense.